# Changing UI in Java Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, tablet

I have an application in my android tablet. The user interface of that application is really bad. I want to make another level -if this word is correct- and use the same application. I won't add new operations, functions. I just want to make the buttons, labels and texts look better.

Is it possible to re-design the UI, or make a layer between the user and application?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:** I don't have the source code, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have the source code?  It's not clear to me.

Comment: Yes it is possible . Depends on How the application was designed.

Comment: I don't know if I've understood your question correctly but you define your layount in xml files so it's separately from application logic so I don't know where is problem.

Comment: I don't have the source code, unfortunately.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to change the UI of an app you haven't made yourself?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't have to be changed. There can be another app that uses the operations in the original one. The new app will do the same operations, but with different buttons. Like calling the app "`originalApp -operationA`, `originalApp -operationB`. However, the original one does not take arguments. Just button clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Use **dip** in your xml views instead of **px**.

To make it look better design it for different screens . Make folders for layouts like

1.layout-small( for phones like samsung galaxy mini)

2.layout-medium(for phones like samsung galaxy note)

3.layout-large(7-10 inch tablets)

4.layout-xlarge(10+ inch devices)

Make sure that file names and views ids should be same to avoid null pointer exceptions in run time . Just play with views attributes and sizes in xml files.

For further details [see this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, It would be tough to changes the UI without sourcecode, as you would not know hows these UI controls will work and look. In simple way you can change the orientation of activities as per need such as portrait to landscape in menifest file, add images for different resolution and adjust padding and all. But this wont be good solution.

check this link, would help you bit [Android App for Tablet and Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956515/android-should-i-split-my-app-into-tablet-and-phone-variants)

Comment: Can I change the way buttons look? Can I make them look better?

Comment: Yes, you can change for sure, just avoid changing the id's

Comment: I may sound like a noob, but, how can I transfer the original application to my computer to change the UI? Is there a "new storage media found" screen shows up when I connect the tablet to my computer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this out first and foremost:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Android is designed to be used on multiple devices. It allows you define different layouts (UI's) for devices of different sizes and screen resolutions.

You can use stuff like [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) as well to divide your apps functionality into smaller pieces and display only those parts which suit the current device.